# Updating Sharepoint List items

Tags: powershell, custom-list, updatelistitems

I got a custom Sharepoint list which has the following list items

```
Hostname  -   IP   -     OS     -    CPUs - RAM -    Disk

Server      1.1.1.1   Server 2003     3      8    Disk C: 20gb
```

If i then change, lets say, the RAM so there is now 12gb (or CPU or any of the other values) i would like it to update it)

I got scripts that pull all the information from the servers via WMI and exporting it to a .csv

The csv layout looks like the following

```
IP,Hostname,OS,CPU,Ram,Disk
1.1.1.1,Server,Server 2003,3,12,Disk C: 20gb
```

Now here's the real question, i got a script that add's the items to the list, but if i run it again it adds the item to the list so its now there twice, (one with the old value and one with the new) but i need a script that can update the diffrent column values if they should change, without having to remove the item and add it again with the new values.

Comment: You need to fire an update operation. However you should have an ID or something that helps you in uniquely identifying your record.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update list item using powershell -

```
$SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://SP -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
```

Next step is to get the list:

```
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["Announcements"]
```

When we have located the list we can retrieve the item. The quickest way is to use the GetItemByID() method:

```
$SPItem = $SPList.GetItemById("1")
```

The example above requires that you know the ID of the item. If you don’t know the items ID you can use the Where-Object cmdlet instead:

```
$SPItem = $SPList.Items | Where { $_["Title"] -eq "New Announcement" }
```

When you’ve retrieved the item you can modify the item information.

```
$SPItem[“Title”] = "MyTitle"
$SPItem[“Body”] = "MyBody"
```

After modifying an item you have to call the Update() method to set the changes.

```
$SPItem.Update()
```

When you’re done, use the Stop-SPAssignment cmdlet to dispose the SPWeb object.

```
Stop-SPAssignment $SPAssignment
```

Source and more info here:
http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/09/addupdatedelete-list-items-using.html

Comment: feel free to ask if you have questions regarding the example

Comment: @Linus, How do we change the List item ID using powershell?