# Cannot set list item value

Tags: powershell, splistitem, spfield

I want to set a ListItem value with **PowerShell (SP2013)**.

As the following screenshot shows, I (the current user) have **Full Control** for this list. However, I **cannot edit any field value**. The value for "GITVersion" is just an example, the same applies to all other fields.

I checked, that the same user can edit when logged in over the web frontend.
I tried other methods to set the value with no success, e.g. ValidateParseAndSet-function for the corresponding field like `$versioninfoGit.Fields["GITVersion"].ValidateParseAndSet(.., "Anything")`

What is wrong or how to find out?

[image: PowerShell screenshot]

**EDIT 1**

In order to be able to try various users when accessing the web and list, I tried **Invoke-Command** for farm, service and other accounts with the result that the part
`$web = Get-SPWeb http://SharePoint`
of the script block fails. According to the exception, the farm is not available.

Lacking other clues, I am guessing a weird permission problem as root cause. But then, I would suspect critical messages in the server logs, exceptions during execution, or at least issues when working with the frontend - none of it.

**EDIT 2**

Note that **I am able to delete and create items**. I also found out (meanwhile) that I can edit those list items I have created with PS, even when the list was re-read in from a new `$web = Get-SPWeb http//sharepoint`
Those existing items where I cannot edit were created by a "real user" in the frontend.

Comment: Kindly check the answer here...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25466/updating-sharepoint-list-items

Comment: I did, but the initial New-SPAssignment, using and stopping it when done does not change my result. And apart from that, the method shown seems analogous to mine. Let me know if I am wrong!

Comment: You are refetching the list item on each row! Fetch it once and store it in a variable, set the field value on that stored object and call `Update()` on it

Answer (score 1):

May be users can only edit their own items. There is a setting somewhere ( see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510951/sharepoint-2013-list-users-only-view-their-own-items )

Comment: After searching somewhere, I found those settings. In my case, all users are  allowed to see  and edit everything.